# How to install properly rpy2 in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, python

I have windows 10.

I set up python and as I can see it work i.e import pandas.

However I try to install rpy2 using pip install rpy2

But I receive this error during the process from command prompt

```
 Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/43/401afad8556bf92b08bd7d422cacac614b0e8dd2bce31848318bbcb18f48/rpy2-3.0.5.tar.gz (117kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 122kB 547kB/s
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: warning: no previously-included files found matching 'setup.pyc'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'examples'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'examples'
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
    pycparser.ply.__pycache__.lex.cpython-37: module references __file__
    pycparser.ply.__pycache__.lex.cpython-37: module MAY be using inspect.getsourcefile
    pycparser.ply.__pycache__.yacc.cpython-37: module references __file__
    pycparser.ply.__pycache__.yacc.cpython-37: module MAY be using inspect.getsourcefile
    pycparser.ply.__pycache__.yacc.cpython-37: module MAY be using inspect.stack
    pycparser.ply.__pycache__.ygen.cpython-37: module references __file__

    Installed c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\cparser.py", line 294, in _parse
        ast = _get_parser().parse(fullcsource)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\c_parser.py", line 152, in parse
        debug=debuglevel)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\ply\yacc.py", line 331, in parse
        return self.parseopt_notrack(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\ply\yacc.py", line 1199, in parseopt_notrack
        tok = call_errorfunc(self.errorfunc, errtoken, self)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\ply\yacc.py", line 193, in call_errorfunc
        r = errorfunc(token)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\c_parser.py", line 1848, in p_error
        column=self.clex.find_tok_column(p)))
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\pycparser-2.19-py3.7.egg\pycparser\plyparser.py", line 67, in _parse_error
        raise ParseError("%s: %s" % (coord, msg))
    pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: <cdef source string>:23:5: before: blah1

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Nathalie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\setup.py", line 184, in <module>
        'rpy2': ['doc/source/rpy2_logo.png', ]}
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 444, in __init__
        k: v for k, v in attrs.items()
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 292, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 732, in finalize_options
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 217, in cffi_modules
        add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 49, in add_cffi_module
        execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\setuptools_ext.py", line 25, in execfile
        exec(code, glob, glob)
      File "rpy/_rinterface_cffi_build.py", line 546, in <module>
        """ if os.name == 'nt' else ''
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\api.py", line 112, in cdef
        self._cdef(csource, override=override, packed=packed, pack=pack)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\api.py", line 126, in _cdef
        self._parser.parse(csource, override=override, **options)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\cparser.py", line 347, in parse
        self._internal_parse(csource)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\cparser.py", line 352, in _internal_parse
        ast, macros, csource = self._parse(csource)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\cparser.py", line 296, in _parse
        self.convert_pycparser_error(e, csource)
      File "c:\users\Nathalie\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\.eggs\cffi-1.12.3-py3.7-win32.egg\cffi\cparser.py", line 325, in convert_pycparser_error
        raise CDefError(msg)
    cffi.CDefError: cannot parse "blah1 ReadConsole;"
    <cdef source string>:23:5: before: blah1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Nathalie\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nq7ozpr0\rpy2\
```

Any idea how can I install it?

Comment: Rpy2 on Windows 10 is busted, with no scheduled delivery date for a fix.  Roll back to an old version.  Otherwise use Linux in a Docker container: (see https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.0.x/html/overview.html ). Or move everything to Linux.  Or dedicate your life to fixing it yourself.  The R open source community lags behind the Python open source community with respect to the Windows platform.  In the words of Rodney Dangerfield "Windows can't get no respect, no respect mind you."

Answer (score 0):

I have windows 10 too. 
To use:

```
conda install rpy2
```

Regards!